# Escaping Javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm looking for the best way to escape some Javascript text in PHP, and `json_encode` is the wrong tool for the job.

The problem comes from this line:

`echo " onclick=\"SwitchDiv('" . $option . "')\"";`

If there's an apostrophe in `$option`, this is a juicy ball of client-side fail.  But doing a straight `json_encode` (which works perfectly well in other contexts) doesn't help:

`echo " onclick=\"SwitchDiv(" . json_encode($option) . ")\"";`

That creates an output string of `onclick="SwitchDiv("athlete's foot")"`, resulting in premature termination of the `onclick` value.  (Which also happens if I enclose the `onclick` value in single quotes.)

Is there an elegant way around this?  Should I just funnel the `json_encode` output through a regex that will escape the single quotes?

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up the `$option` value as you allude to at the end of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` is the right tool for the job. Your problem arises from the fact that you are also including that Javascript in an *HTML attribute*, thus it also needs to be `htmlspecialchars`-encoded.

```
echo " onclick=\"SwitchDiv(" . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($option)) . ")\"";
```